# CSS keyframe animate border issue

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to animate smoothly some css triangles, I have this:

but nothing happen's - can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Thanks:

```
    .angle-1 {
        position: absolute; bottom: 0;
        width: 0; height: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 200px 0 0 1440px;
        border-color: transparent transparent transparent #007bff;
        opacity: 0.7;
        -webkit-animation: moveangle1 2s infinite;
        -moz-animation: moveangle1 2s infinite;
        -o-animation: moveangle1 2s infinite;
        animation: moveangle1 2s infinite;
    }
        @keyframes moveangle1,
        @-o-keyframes moveangle1,
        @-moz-keyframes moveangle1,
        @-webkit-keyframes moveangle1 {
            0%   { border-width: 200px 0 0 1440px; opacity: 0.7; }
            100% { border-width: 400px 0 0 1000px; opacity: 0.4; }
        }
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/sp2emgtc/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: However, I suspect `border-width` as **shorthand** is not animatable. Try animating the individual properties. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-width

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D I added a JSFiddle with the HTML Div that was missing.
I've tried with the full border-top-width and that didn't help. 

Also to note, the opacity is not altering either.

Comment: Ahh...I see the problem. Answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot combine vendor prefixed keyframe statements into a single rule.

They must be stated separately.

```css
.angle-1 {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 200px 0 0 1440px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #007bff;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-animation: moveangle1 2s infinite;
  animation: moveangle1 2s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveangle1 {
  0% {
    border-width: 200px 0 0 1440px;
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  100% {
    border-width: 400px 0 0 1000px;
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
}
@keyframes moveangle1 {
  0% {
    border-width: 200px 0 0 1440px;
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  100% {
    border-width: 400px 0 0 1000px;
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="angle-1">

</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Paulie_D !